# Displaying a ListView using SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview

A part of the project I'm working on is searching about places in a database. The user first chooses a category, then the search criteria and the results should be displayed in a list view in which the items are from the database. Only one works right and the rest don't, even though they have similar code.

The first search category is `Hotel`s which works perfectly fine, the rest of the categories are not working properly, the methods are correct but displaying the data is wrong, instead of displaying the name it displays packageName.tableName@weirdNumber example(`egypt.database.NileCruise@44f40448`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `ArrayAdapter` will call the method `toString` on your object to get a `String` to show in the list row.

You probably implemented the method `toString` for the class `Hotel` but forgot to implement it for the class `NileCruise` and you end up with the default implementation of `toString`(that returns what you currently see).

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! It's been bothering me for a while and I couldn't figure out what was wrong! Thank you

Comment: @MahaK If my answer helped you please mark it as correct with the check mark.